# .htaccess accounts for gzip encoding and caching but YSlow reports an 'F' on both

Tags: php, apache, caching, compression, gzip

I am new to optimization techniques such as gzip compression and caching. After some research on the net, I realized that this is possible through .htaccess based on some apache handlers. i had enquired my webhosting to know if mod_deflate and mod_headers libraries are present and available

I even checked through firebug. It shows the request headers "Accept-Encoding     gzip,deflate" but there is no "Content-encoding" in the response field. Can someone please help me out on where am going wrong?

Following is the code of .htaccess file

```
            Options -Indexes
            Options +FollowSymlinks
            RewriteEngine on

            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

            <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/html text/plain text/xml
            DeflateCompressionLevel 9
            </IfModule>


            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Expires headers (for better cache control)
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

            # These are pretty far-future expires headers.
            # They assume you control versioning with filename-based cache busting
            # Additionally, consider that outdated proxies may miscache
            # www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

            # If you don't use filenames to version, lower the CSS and JS to something like
            # "access plus 1 week" or so.

            <IfModule mod_expires.c>
              ExpiresActive on

            # Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
              ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

            # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
              ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"

            # Your document html
              ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

            # Data
              ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
              ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
              ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"

            # Feed
              ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
              ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"

            # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
              ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"

            # Media: images, video, audio
              ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

            # HTC files (css3pie)
              ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"

            # Webfonts
              ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
              ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

            # CSS and JavaScript
              ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
              ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

            </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your host provider has both modules enabled? Have you checked another website hosted in the same provider? Sometimes small host providers turn off mod_deflate on shared plans to save some CPU therefore increase sharing.

Trying curl any js resource on your site, e.g.:

```
curl -I "http://yslow.org/yslow-bookmarklet.js" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
```

You should get something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.13
Date: Wed, 06 Jun 2012 18:31:25 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Last-Modified: Fri, 25 May 2012 16:11:28 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 07 Jun 2012 18:31:25 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Look for `Content-Encoding` to make sure **mod_deflate** is ON and also `Expires` and `Cache-Control` for **mod_expires**.